# need path name of folder "DCIM"

Tags: android, file, path, move

I want to use the renameTo method to copy a file into another folder but I don't know the path. I want to put a file into the "DCIM" folder in the internal Storage.

```
oldFile.renameTo(new File("That is the path name I need" + "/myData.txt"));
```

Thank you very much!!!

Comment: have you try this `String dcim_path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM).getAbsolutePath();`

Comment: @Erman
I tried out the following Code but the System.out.println returns false and it doesn't rename the File. My Code looks like this:



        String dcim_path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory( Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM).getAbsolutePath();

        System.out.println(
                new File(dcim_path + "/myData.png").renameTo(new File(dcim_path + "/myDataa.png"))
        );

The File path it uses is /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/myData.png

Answer (score 0):

```
File dcim=Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);

oldFile.renameTo(new File(dcim, "myData.txt"));
```

Comment: @Shade: Please do not ask questions by posting answers to your own question. To work with `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()`, not only do you need `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`, but you also need to request that permission at runtime on Android 6.0+ devices. See https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting for details.

Comment: requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, PermissionRequest);

That one doesn't functionate

Comment: @Shade: You define that value yourself. As the documentation that I linked to says, "...after the user responds to the prompt, the system calls the app's [`onActivityResult()`] callback method with the results, passing the same request code that the app passed to `requestPermissions()`".

Comment: I am sorry but I dont understand, what do i have to add?